# model combines EffcientNetB0 and LSTM with X_train size is (150,150,3), model does not fit…

Tags: python, tensorflow

trying to Combine `EffcientNetB0` and `LSTM` with `X_train` size is (150,150,3), but model does not fit…..

With error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5, 5,    1280), found shape=(None, 150, 150, 3)
```

Code:

```
input_shape=(150,150,3)
effnet = EfficientNetB0(weights=None,include_top=False,input_shape=input_shape
effnets=effnet.input_shape#(150,150,3)
Res_model = effnet.output
print(Res_model.shape)                              #(None, 5, 5, 1280)
model = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(Res_model)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 1280)
model=  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu")(model)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 512)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(model, training=True)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 512)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='softmax')(model)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 32)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=effnet.input, outputs = model)
#print(model.input_shape)                            #(None, 150, 150, 3)
#print(model.output_shape)                           #(None, 32)
#using LSTM

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
# Define the input shape for the sequence data
sequence_input = Input(shape=(150,150))
print(sequence_input.shape)

# Instantiate the LSTM model
lstm_model = LSTM(32)(sequence_input)
print(lstm_model.shape)

# Concatenate the output of the EfficientNetB0 model and the LSTM model
concatenated = Concatenate()([model.output, lstm_model])

# Add a dense layer to the concatenated output
output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)#input_shape=[(None, 5, 5, 1280), (None, 32)]
# Define the final model
model1 = Model(inputs=(Res_model,sequence_input), outputs=output)
model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = 'Adam', metrics= ['accuracy'])
history = model1.fit((X_train,y_train), batch_size=32,
                          epochs = 2, validation_split=0.1,verbose=1)

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5, 5,    1280), found shape=(None, 150, 150, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your questions there are some small details and suggestions I would like to propose for your code:

- I don't understand the purpose of `effnets` since it's basically a copy of `input_shape`.
- Then I see sometimes you call the libray where the function is:

  ```
  model=  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu")(model)
  ```

  and sometimes you don't:

  ```
  effnet = EfficientNetB0(weights=None,include_top=False,input_shape=input_shape
  ```

  My suggestion for you is: call the library everytime because
  otherwise you'll need to manually call it for every layer/model/function you use.

  So instead of:

  ```
  from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0 
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM 
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate 
  ...
  ```

  You can simply:

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf 
  from tensorflow import keras

  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(... 
  tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(...
  ```

About your code:

```
input_shape = (150, 150, 3)

effnet = EfficientNetB0(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(effnet.output)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.5)(x, training=True)
output = Dense(32, activation='softmax')(x)
model1 = Model(inputs=effnet.input, outputs=output)

sequence_input = Input(shape=(150, 150))
lstm_model = LSTM(32)(sequence_input)
concatenated = Concatenate()([model1.output, lstm_model])
output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)

model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, sequence_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit([X_train_image, X_train_sequence], y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=2, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
```

Since your final layer is a Dense with 2 neurons you are doing binary classification so you should use binary_crossentropy as a loss function.

You can always use:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

to see a plot of the entire model with shapes to see if everything looks good.

Hope I've helped!